# How to implement login to wordpress site via iphone app?

Tags: ios, iphone, wordpress, authentication

I am working on creating ios app for iphone where users have an access to my wordpress site can only login to. My login address is www.example.com/wp-login.php How should I implement it? I am  a beginner in ios development.

EDIT: The app will only show user's info and previously submitted forms. It will not show any other content from the website. Once user's are authorized they will be able to fill out new form and submit or see their previously submitted forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you want to do.

**Normally we should not display only a Website content within a WebView, for this you can Use Safari and add a Basic Authentication to your Website.**

Apps normally fetch content from a API on the Webserver to retrieve Content, parse the Data and then display it natively.

For Wordpress you can write your own Plugin for that, or use an existing one.

This for the Content:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

And this Plugin provides authentication support for WP:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-auth/

Comment: The app will only display user info and previously submitted forms by user. Once they login they will have options to view their history or fill out new form (including taking picture and submitting). Is it possibly to send data to wp database through app?

Comment: Yes, you only need to extend the json-api php plugin or create your own plugin which handles the actions and writes it to the database.